# How to convert Flash movieclip animations to unity animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, flash

I am new to Unity and want to convert all my flash games to unity. I am trying to convert movie clips from Flash Animate CC to Unity, but not found any answer, please help.

I have tried to convert each movie clip to a sprite sheet and .png files. But it is increasing overload as each movie clip converts it into 150-200 png files.

I am expecting to play animations without converting it into png files or sprite sheet.

Comment: Since new to Unity, why not read the manual to check for possibilites? Does it support animated GIF? Is that an option for your animations?... **(1)** `but not found any answer, please help`... [unity play swf](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&ei=A8wcXZ7DDdml1fAPr5mJoA0&q=unity+play+swf). Even page 1 has options like: GAF, uniSWF and LWF. **(2)** Did you try exporting animations as video? If you don't like sprite-sheets then either recreate animations in Unity or stick with Flash. **(3)** `each movie clip converts it into 150-200 png files` what type of animation is in each movieclip?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but I want to implement interactive animations (each movie clip is divided into two parts i.e. idle animation and after tap animation), so I think, can't implement video.

I will try Animated GIF, GAF,uniSWF, LWF

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool called TexturePacker which can automatically pack your sprites into spritesheets for you:

https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker

You can just drag and drop your image sequence into that tool and export as a single sheet.

Other than that, there are some paid assets on the store for importing .swf content, check out this one for instance:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/flash-animation-toolset-trial-73896